# Pass Value to Subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

```
        SELECT
            u.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.shot_id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownFavorites,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.shot_id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownStars,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownShots,
            ( SELECT AVG(p.count)
                FROM points p
                LEFT JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = **U.ID** AND p.shot_id = s.id
                WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            ) AS attention,
            ( SELECT SUM(p.count)
                FROM points p
                LEFT JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = **U.ID** AND s.id = p.shot_id
            ) AS popularity
        FROM users u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = u.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.user_id = u.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.user_id = u.id
        WHERE u.username = ?;
```

I got two subselects which use the parameter u.id (marked in the query). If i do the sql like this it will generate somthing like that:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'
```

Means, the `u.id` id is NOT defined in the `SubSelects`. But in the `MainSelect` I choose from the `users` table, where `u.id` exists.

To my question: Is there a way to pass the selected `u.id` value to the `Subselects` with common sql?

Comment: It's not possible use a join in a subquery with a column from the outer query in the join condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget GROUP BY in the subqueries:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    COALECSE(a.average, 0) attention,
    COALESCE(p.total, 0) popular,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.shot_id) AS ownFavorites,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.shot_id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownStars,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownShots
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        s.user_id,
        AVG(p.count) average
    FROM
        shots s
    JOIN
        points p
        ON s.id = p.shot_id
    WHERE
        s.date >+ CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
    GROUP BY s.user_id
    ) a
    ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        s.user_id,
        SUM(p.count) total
    FROM
        shots s
    JOIN
        points p
        ON s.id = p.shot_id
    GROUP BY s.user_id
    ) p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.username = 'user'
```

Comment: nice solution. Worked after change in first `left join` the `where` statement the `s.date` to `p.date` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the selects into a subselect join.

```
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT AVG(p.count) AverageOfP, p.shot_id
            FROM points p             
            WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
        ) p ON p.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT SUM(p.count) SumOfP, p.shot_id
            FROM points p             
        ) p2 ON p2.shot_id = s.id
```

The s table is already joined to u and should be good.  Then in your select you can just select AverageOfP and SumOfP.

Comment: I had something like that before and was changing the join's that I solve. I think you are right here.

Comment: notice: the `SUM`should be from all records in the points table. the `AVG` is from the records of the two last days

Comment: @user3389733 Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this may work.  The select doesn't have knowledge of the of the users table the way you had it.  I believe this would have knowledge of Users.

```
    SELECT
        u.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.shot_id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownFavorites,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.shot_id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownStars,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.id SEPARATOR ",") AS ownShots,
        A.Attention, P.Popularity
      FROM users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      ( SELECT AVG(p.count) attention
            FROM points p
            LEFT JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = **U.ID** AND p.shot_id = s.id
            WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
        ) AS A,
        ( SELECT SUM(p.count) popularity
            FROM points p
            LEFT JOIN shots s ON s.user_id = **U.ID** AND s.id = p.shot_id
        ) AS P
    WHERE u.username = ?;
```

Comment: Its likely the same as @gervs, but thank you for your affort. you got a vote up XD